# How do I delete the "Hello from the pygame community" console alert while using pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame

Every time I run my python game, I get an annoying alert in the console saying:

`Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html`

How do I delete this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Modifying the library would mean that you would have to modify the library everywhere you ship your code, and is generally not a good idea.**

The upcoming release `1.9.5` of pygame will include an option to turn off the message without modifying the library:

You have to set the environment variable `PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT` to any value.

On Windows: `set PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT=1`

On Linux etc.: `export PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT=1`

Or even in *your* code:

```
from os import environ
environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = '1'

import pygame  # it is important to import pygame after that
```

Comment: Note that this would only work if you build pygame from source, or wait for the 1.9.5 release.

Comment: Is removing the print statement against their toc?  From what I read, it seems like they don't care.

Comment: @Jane, I don't know, but my point is, that modifying the library is a bad idea: imagine the library gets an update, how do you merge that, or you send your program to someone else, then they also have to modify the library.

Comment: Works perfectly, but unfortunately it violates PEP 8. ;-(

Answer (score 3):

### Mac OS

- Navigate to: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygame/` and open `_init_.py`

(hint: this is the Library for your Macintosh HD, not your users library)

- scroll down to the bottom of the page, then delete the line saying:
  `print('Hello from the pygame community ... )`

If you can't find your Library folder, then you probably still have the default settings set to hide it.

- type `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES;` in the terminal
- hold option + right click on finder and click relaunch.

### Windows

(this is untested, if you have problems let me know so I can update)

- Navigate to: `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pygame` and open `_init_.py`
- scroll down to the bottom of the page, then delete the line saying: `print('Hello from the pygame community ... )`

Comment: This works out great! I had been wondering how to do this for some time! Thank you!!